# PDE on the line

Tags: differential-equations

In my work I faced a system of PDE of the form
\begin{align}
      \varphi^\prime_v(t,v)|_{v=X_t} = \sigma(t,X_t),\newline
      \varphi^\prime_t(t,v)|_{v=X_t} = b(t,X_t),
\end{align}

where $t\in[0,T]$, $v\in\mathbf R$,  $X_t$ is known continuous function of unbounded variation, $\varphi(t,v)$ is unknown, $\varphi^\prime_v(t,v) = \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \varphi(t,v)$,  $\varphi^\prime_t(t,v) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \varphi(t,v)$ and there is an initial value $\varphi(0,X_0) =  x_0$. Function $\varphi(t,X_t)$ is to be determined.

Roughly this is a system of PDE 
\begin{align}
      \varphi^\prime_v(t,v)= \sigma(t,v),\newline
      \varphi^\prime_t(t,v) = b(t,v),
\end{align}
defined on the line $(t,X_t)$.

I need to find a solution for this system, but yet haven't dealt with such equations and don't even know if they have any special name, so that I could search. I will be very happy if somebody gives me recommendations on textbooks which consider this kind of problems.

Comment: Doesn't it reduce immediately to ODEs?  Your 1st DE says $\phi(t,v) = \sigma(t,X_t)v+c_t$ which you then plug into your 2nd DE to solve for $c_t$.  

Comment: Which functions are given, and which are unknown?

Comment: Have edited the question. So now it's clear which functions are known and which are to be determined and it doesn't reduce to ODEs.

Comment: If $X_t$ is a fixed function of $t$, isn't your PDE too underdetermined?  You're only describing the partial derivatives of $\phi$ along the curve $(t,X_t)$.  So it look (to me) like the only thing going on is your PDE is an ODE for the function $f(t) = \phi(t,X_t)$ given by $f'(t) = \sigma(t,X_t)X'_t + b(t,X_t)$.   And now this is integrable since on the right hand side you've got a function of $t$ alone. 

Comment: Again, sorry, my fault, forgot to mention that $X_t$ has unbounded variation, so it can't be differentiable.

Comment: Are you really sure this is what you're studying?  What you've written down is not much of a constraint on $\phi(t,v)$. 